# Aggregate clause on varchar datatype in subquery

Tags: sql

I'd like to do the following with a sub query, even though I can do it another way.  I'm querying a large junction table and inside of that query I want to get a count of all the county names that come up more than X number of times.

```
select v.id, k.countyName
from v inner join k on v.countyID=k.countyID inner join
icd_jxn on v.id = icd_jxn.id
where k.countyName in
(select count(k.countyName) from k
having count(k.countyName) > 10)
```

The error given is `conversion failed when converting the varchar value X to int`.  I don't want to do any conversion, I just want a number of the times the county name appears on the table.

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your inner query is only returning a count.  Your query needs to be this:

```
select v.id, k.countyName 
from v inner join k on v.countyID=k.countyID inner join 
icd_jxn on v.id = icd_jxn.id 
where k.countyName in 
(select k.countyName from k 
group by k.countyName
having count(k.countyName) > 10)
```

Comment: all of them fields named ID are ints and countyName is varchar

Comment: this runs but it doesn't do what i wanted.  The table k doesn't have any repeats of county name, the outer query does.  if I do greater 0 then I get the entire table (800k rows).  but as soon as I do >1, i get 0 rows returned.  Even though there are 100s of thousands of repeats.

Comment: Then you need to do the join in the inner query to find the total count per county in your data

Answer (score 0):

You can try the following

```
select v.id, k.countyName
from v inner join k on v.countyID=k.countyID 
       inner join icd_jxn on v.id = icd_jxn.id
where k.countyName in
(
    select k.countyName from k
    group by k.countyName
    having count(k.countyName) > 10
)
```

The problem is you have select the `count` and checked the `varchar` type in your IN subquery. So, you should select the `countyName`

Comment: This won't work, your `IN` can't be linked to 2 columns being returned.

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to see where country name IN a count (thus comparing varchar to integer)

```
select v.id, k.countyName
from v 
inner join k on v.countyID=k.countyID 
inner join icd_jxn on v.id = icd_jxn.id
where k.countyName in
(
   select k.countyName as c from k
   having count(k.countyName) > 10 
   group by k.countyName
)
```

Comment: This won't work, your `IN` can't be linked to 2 columns being returned.

Answer (score 0):

In your query you are compering `k.CountryName` varchar type to `Count` int type that is cause of error.
Try this

```
select v.id, k.countyName
from v inner join k on v.countyID=k.countyID inner join
icd_jxn on v.id = icd_jxn.id
where k.countyName in
(select k.countyName from k
group by k.countyName
having count(k.countyName) > 10)
```